# Update Not Working With Case...When...Else

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This seems like it should be very easy, and when I do a simple select, everything works fine, but when I try to run an Update, I get an error that says 'Incorrect syntax near CASE'.

```
Update    TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST 
SET       CURRENCY_FBNK = CURRENCY.Currency_Code,
          CURRENCY_ASOFDATE = CURRENCY.ASOFDATE,
          CURRENCY_MID_REVAL_RATE = CURRENCY.MID_REVAL_RATE,
          ORIGINAL_AMOUNT = MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL
          REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = REVAL_BALANCE
                CASE WHEN CURRENCY.ID IN('AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD','XAG','XAU','XPD','XPT') 
                    THEN (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL * CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate)
                    ELSE (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL / CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate) END AS REVAL_BALANCE
From      TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST AS CURRENCY INNER JOIN JOIN TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST AS MM_HIST 
          ON CURRENCY.Currency_Code = MM_HIST.Currency
          AND CURRENCY.ASOFDATE = MM_HIST.ASOFDATE
```

What the heck is wrong here?

Comment: What is being updated to the result of the `CASE`? You also appear to be missing a comma after `MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL`

Comment: (1) did you get fed up of adding commas (2) what are you trying to assign the result of that CASE expression to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a coma between `MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL` and `REPORTABLE_AMOUNT`, and another one between `REVAL_BALANCE` and `CASE`. Also, you're only returning a value with your `CASE` statement, but you're not assigning it to anything.

Assuming by field names that you want to assign the result of the `CASE` to `REPORTABLE_AMOUNT`

```
Update    TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST 
SET       CURRENCY_FBNK = CURRENCY.Currency_Code,
          CURRENCY_ASOFDATE = CURRENCY.ASOFDATE,
          CURRENCY_MID_REVAL_RATE = CURRENCY.MID_REVAL_RATE,
          ORIGINAL_AMOUNT = MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL,
          REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = CASE WHEN CURRENCY.ID IN('AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD','XAG','XAU','XPD','XPT') 
                THEN (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL * CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate)
                ELSE (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL / CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate) END
From      TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST AS CURRENCY INNER JOIN JOIN TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST AS MM_HIST 
          ON CURRENCY.Currency_Code = MM_HIST.Currency
          AND CURRENCY.ASOFDATE = MM_HIST.ASOFDATE
```

Comment: Also missing comma after `MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL`

Comment: Ah!!  That's it Josh!  Thanks.  Time to head home now and take a break.  I guess too much time in the office makes a person temporarily dumb.

Comment: I'm curious what kind of business rule needs division instead of multiplication depending on currency? are conversion factors stored reciprocally for some currencies?

Comment: I asked the same exact question!  Basically, when it comes to FX you should multiply everything by the exchange rate, or you  should divide everything by the exchange rate.  At my s*** a** company, they have their own (non-normalized) ways of doing everything.

Answer (score 1):

The whole `CASE...END` forms an expression. Your mistake is that you assign the alias REVAL_BALANCE to the result of the CASE expression, which makes sense in a select but not in an update.

Use an assignment for the update, like this:

```
REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = CASE WHEN CURRENCY.ID IN('AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD','XAG','XAU','XPD','XPT') 
                THEN (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL * CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate)
                ELSE (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL / CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate) END
```

Or did you need to multiply `REVAL_BALANCE` with a currency conversion rate? In this case you just forgot to type the multiplication operator (*). This could be:

```
UPDATE TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST SET       
    CURRENCY_FBNK = CURRENCY.Currency_Code,
    CURRENCY_ASOFDATE = CURRENCY.ASOFDATE,
    CURRENCY_MID_REVAL_RATE = CURRENCY.MID_REVAL_RATE,
    ORIGINAL_AMOUNT = MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL,
    REPORTABLE_AMOUNT = REVAL_BALANCE * CASE WHEN 
        CURRENCY.ID IN('AUD','EUR','GBP','NZD','XAG','XAU','XPD','XPT') 
        THEN (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL * CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate)
        ELSE (MM_HIST.PRINCIPAL / CURRENCY.Mid_Reval_Rate) END
From TBL_FBNK_CURRENCY_HIST AS CURRENCY 
INNER JOIN JOIN TBL_MULTI_MM_HIST AS MM_HIST ON CURRENCY.Currency_Code = MM_HIST.Currency AND CURRENCY.ASOFDATE = MM_HIST.ASOFDATE
```